# How to get pixel bit count using PixelFormat in libav

Tags: c++, directshow, libav

Is there any way to get pixel's bit count from codecContext.pix_fmt of type PixelFormat? I do it manually using switch:

```
switch (OUT_IMAGE_FORMAT)
{
    case PIX_FMT_RGB24:
        pVideoInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
        do_something();
        break;

    //etc
}
```

but this requires manual updates every time libav will add or delete some pixel formats. Or if I will need to add some pixel format that wasn't supported earlier.

P.S. I need it to fill CMediaType for DirectShow filters, so bits_per_raw_sample isn't appropriate since it's for internal libav usage as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
#include "libavutil/pixdesc.h"

pVideoInfo->bmiHeader.biBitCount =  av_get_bits_per_pixel(&av_pix_fmt_descriptors[OUT_IMAGE_FORMAT]);
```

http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h.html

Comment: It's what I'm looking for, but there is a little problem still unresolved on MSVC which I use with libav: error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _av_pix_fmt_descriptors. As [this](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1514) topic says I can fix it by manual editing libav headers which I don't want to do, or by redeclaring av_pix_fmt_descriptors[]. Is there any better way to solve this problem?

Comment: You might try using "workaround" described here https://lists.libav.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2010-October/098473.html